# Block calls for everyone except for contacts

Tags: calls, silent-mode, mute

Is there a way to block (or mute) all calls except for those on my contact list?

I'm using android 4.1.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app [Calls Blacklist](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.vladlee.easyblacklist) mentions exactly that as one possible use:

> There are four block modes of call blocker:
>
> - Blacklist
> - All except the whitelist
> - **All except contacts**
> - All numbers

(emphasis mine). There are plenty other similar apps available, just search for "blacklist" or "call blocker" on the playstore.

[Update 25/5/22] In the free version the block behaviour is 'ignore', so the call still appears to ring for the person calling. In the [pro version](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.vladlee.callsblacklist) you can choose to immediately reject the call.

Comment: Worth noting that the app mentioned is FREE (as in beer). Great because blocking through phone settings seems to vary between phones, but apps don't.

Comment: I just installed this app and it seems to work well.  Depending on the settings you choose, the blocked calls may or may not be able to leave voice mail messages.

Answer (score 7):

Although you mentioned using Android 4.1.2, I recently stumbled across this question and thought a more recent answer might be useful to others:

On Android 5.0 "Lollipop" and later this can be accomplished using the ["Priority only" Do Not Disturb mode](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295):

#### Configure Do Not Disturb Priority Allowances

> 1. Open your device's **Settings** app.
> 2. Tap **Sound**, then **Do Not Disturb** preferences, then **Priority only allows**.
> 3. Set **Calls** to **From contacts only** and adjust any other preferences for this mode to your liking.

#### Turn on Do Not Disturb "Priority only" mode

> 1. Swipe down from the top of your screen with 2 fingers.
> 2. Under **Do not disturb** or your current option, tap the Down arrow.
> 3. Turn on **Do not disturb**.
> 4. Pick **Priority only**.
> 5. Choose how long you want this setting to last.
> 6. Tap **Done**.

Comment: Am I right in thinking this will only silence the call, not stop it from ringing altogether?

Comment: @ChrisA I believe so.  My understanding is that Do Not Disturb does not automatically decline incoming calls or hide the notifications; it only disables any ringtone or vibration.

Comment: Calls Blacklist Pro did the trick for me https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vladlee.callsblacklist&hl=en_GB

Comment: @ChrisA That's great!  I'd encourage you to submit it as an answer to make it easier for others to find.  (Or suggest it as an edit to [Izzy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/52837) if Blacklist Pro is the replacement for Blacklist Plus, since it's the same developer.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it exists on the S3 mini, but on the regular S3 running 4.1 and later, there's a thing called Blocking Mode that will allow you to block incoming calls (and other notifications) from non-contacts, or limit it further to only favorite contacts or make a custom list of allowed callers.

Answer (score 0):

It so often happens to me in all things Android, what worked yesterday may not work today… the above may be valid, but didn’t work on my phone. If your phone is rooted, or you can obtain and install a silent ringtone, the following has worked perfectly for me over several years and several versions of Android:

1. Download and copy a silent ringtone file to your phone’s ringtone library. (Google: SILENT OGG for a file)
2. Set your default Ringtone to use this file.
3. Set the individual contacts who can call you directly to any sound producing ringtone you want.

The neat thing about this is that if someone has not been assigned a sound producing ringtone, they can still leave a message for you and you can call them back if you want. If the call is from a telemarketer or a phone spammer, they will rarely, if ever leave you a message. Is that perfect or what?

Tip: If you want to occasionally receive a call from someone to whom you would normally not respond, e.g., the notification that “your table in the restaurant is now available,” create a dummy contact such as “Guest” and update this contact’s phone number as necessary.

PS:  If any Android programmer has the spunk to do this, I’d like to help.

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 upon selecting "Do not Disturb," will block all calls except those on your contact list.  Happy days.