# Block phone calls which are not saved on mobile

Tags: applications, contacts, calls

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6. I  want to block all calls which are not saved in my contact list: the phone should not ring, but the blocked call should be recorded in the call history so I can call back if I wish.

I have found many apps but they reject calls *after ringing once.* So strangers think he/has not recieved call and cut.

*Is there any help or setting in Android?*

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to supress the ring without root powers. You could try [Block Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jachness.blockcalls), which is a privacy-friendly call blocker app that has the option to block calls from numbers which are not in your contact list. They write "It is known that some devices vibrate or ring a few seconds before the app manage to hang up the call", so this might be device specific.

Comment: Thanks for link. I've install extension.it just reject call not block

Comment: How do you assume blocking should work if not by rejecting? The only alternative I know of would be simply suppressing the ring tone (i.e. let it continue ringing, but soundlessly, until the caller hangs up). That could possibly be achieved using some automation app (incoming call › not in contacts › ring volume=0; call finished › restore ring volume).

Comment: I want it shoul work like when stranger call it turns flight mode

Comment: Then you'll have to look into [automation](/tags/automation/info). No such setting exists in Android itself, and I'm not aware of any app acting like that either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block calls for everyone except for contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52833/block-calls-for-everyone-except-for-contacts)

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is. Download 360 antivirus. In the its security menu you can block all unknown numbers, fortunately there's a history of the caller and the number of times the number has called. If you are having issues finding it, you can reach out to me.

Comment: Can you mention link please?

Comment: No longer in Playstore AFAIK. And comes with a bunch of trackers (7 ad modules, 4 analytic modules). You certainly wouldn't want that. Apart from that, it will do the very same: rejecting calls.