# Block non-contact callers

Tags: call-screening

I was wondering if there was a way to block all non-contact callers on my Samsung Galaxy A20 operating system Android 10. I have been through the settings and the only option I have is block contacts or block unknown callers I'm not sure if that just means private calls or non-contact collars. I'm unable to find a solution on YouTube so I'm hoping somebody on here can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block calls for everyone except for contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52833/block-calls-for-everyone-except-for-contacts)

Answer (score 1):

One way that I know how to do this is though [Android's Do Not Disturb feature](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9069335?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20turn%20Do%20Not%20Disturb,it%20to%20silence%20your%20phone).

You basically keep your phone in "do not disturb" mode always, then manually set who is allowed to interrupt you.

Some of the options for who can interrupt you are:

- **Conversations:**

  - All conversations
  - Priority conversations. To choose
    which conversations are priority conversations, tap Settings.
  - None
- **Calls:**

  - Anyone, contacts or starred contacts
  - Repeat callers. To let a
    call through if the same person calls twice in 15 minutes, turn on
    Allow repeat callers.
- **Messages:**

  - Anyone, contacts or starred contacts
  - None
  - Reminders
  - Events

---

Basically, this is essentially a white-list approach as opposed to a black-list approach.

There may be third-party apps that can accomplish what you are asking, but the above is a stock built-in to Android option for you.

Answer (score -1):

I use an Android app called Calls Blacklist. Settings - Blocking - Unknown Numbers (Block all numbers except Contacts)

Comment: Hello. Can you provide link for this app?